# Image tag inside content tag is not available in the resulted string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my helper I have an image tag inside a content tag, unfortunately the image tag is not their in the resulted string from the wrapper content tag (`li`), I don't know what is wrong with it or missing, hope you guide me. Here is the code:

```
  li = content_tag :li do
    image_tag avatar_url_helper(actors.first)
    content_tag :div, class: "notification_content" do 
      # some content that is rendered correctly
    end
  end
```

so the resulted `li` string doesn't contain the image tag, what is missing or how to concatenate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `image_tag`, `content_tag`, ... helpers return strings containing HTML. When you give one of the helpers a block, the helper inserts the block's return value into the generated string. The block you're handing to `content_tag :li` doesn't return the `<img>`, it just returns the inner `<div>` so it is functionally equivalent to:

```
li = content_tag :li do
  content_tag :div, class: "notification_content" do 
    # some content that is rendered correctly
  end
end
```

If you want both the `<img>` and `<div>` inside the `<li>` then you'll have to say so:

```
li = content_tag :li do
  img = image_tag avatar_url_helper(actors.first)
  div = content_tag :div, class: "notification_content" do 
    # some content that is rendered correctly
  end
  img + div
end
```